# Post image via webservices

Tags: services

I tried to create a node through external application using web services. This having only two fields node title and cck field image. i will grateful if anyone share the JSON format to post the images. I tried using format that mentioned below link but its failed means image not uploaded.

https://www.drupal.org/node/2195165

Any one guide me do this.

Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

URL: http://example.com/service_enpoint/file

Method: POST

file: (file to be uploaded in base 64 encoded format)

filename :plus-box.jpg

uid: 55

The jpg file should be uploaded in base 64 encoded format.

As response you will get a fid , which you will have to pass in the image field while creating the node.